# SQL DATA BASE QUERY

Tags: mysql, sql

City

```
Id      Name
1       Delhi
2       Noida
3       Gurugram
```

Parameter

```
Id      Name
1       Health
2       Education
3       Employment
```

Rating

```
Id          Rating  City_Id   Param_Id  Quarter     Year    Value_Date
1           7.5     1         1         Q1          2017    2017-02-15
2           6.3     1         1         Q1          2017    2017-02-13
3           6.9     1         1         Q1          2017    2017-02-20
4           8.2     1         1         Q2          2017    2017-04-05
5           5.5     1         1         Q2          2018    2017-12-13
6           7.6     1         1         Q3          2017    2017-08-20
7           4.5     2         1         Q1          2017    2017-02-17
8           5.3     2         1         Q1          2017    2017-02-14
9           6.9     2         1         Q1          2017    2017-02-25
10          7.2     2         1         Q2          2017    2017-08-05
11          8.5     2         1         Q2          2018    2017-12-13
12          9.6     2         1         Q3          2017    2017-08-20
13          3.5     3         1         Q2          2018    2017-12-14
14          4.6     3         1         Q4          2017    2017-08-17
15          5.5     3         1         Q2          2018    2017-12-20
16          7.6     3         1         Q3          2017    2017-08-15
17          7.5     3         1         Q2          2018    2017-12-18
18          8.6     3         1         Q3          2017    2017-08-24
19          7.5     1         2         Q1          2020    2018-05-25
20          6.3     2         2         Q3          2018    2018-17-13
21          6.9     3         3         Q2          2019    2019-06-20
```

I want to fetch the data from the Rating Table. I have a list of city ids, parameter ids, Quarter and Year. For Example city_id = [1,2,3], paramter_id = [1], quarter = Q3 and Year= 2017 then the output id from Rating tables should be 6, 12 and 18. 6 and 12 are fine but 18 is selected because if same quarter and year is present then we fetch the data using latest value_date.

Another case city_id = [1,2,3], paramter_id = [1], quarter = Q4 and Year= 2017 then the output id from Rating tables should be 5,11,14. 14 is fine but 5 and 11 is selected because if Quarter and year together are not present then we calculate the max date of queries period that shoub be 2017-12-31 (Q4 -2017) and apply less than equal to value_date (must be earliest)

Comment: A better title would be great and surely not difficult... and no need to SHOUT in any case. Also, did you try any cod yet, and what specific problems did you encounter with it?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: There are 2 conditions
    1. If Quarter and Year matches
    2. If Quarter and Year does not match
I am able to handle both cases separately but not together

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . I am thinking window functions.  So filter for all rows whose year/quarter is less than or equal to the quarter you want.  Then enumerate the rows backwards:

```
select r.*
from (select r.*,
             row_number() over (partition by city_id, parameter_id order by year desc, quarter desc) as seqnum
      from rating r
      where city_id in (1, 2, 3) and parameter_id = 1 and
            year <= 2017 and
            (year < 2017 or quarter <= 'Q4')
     ) r
where (year = 2017 and quarter = 'Q4') or
      seqnum = 1;
```

The filter chooses either the correct quarter or the first row.

Comment: can I run this query in php my admin?

Comment: @Shubham . . . I see no reason why not.  It is actually standard SQL.